# ajax call in filter search is not working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i have bootstrap tabs along with filters. When user selects the filter and submits, the ajax call is generated and tabs should display the content.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs " role="tablist">
<li class="active col-md-3"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Notes</a></li>
<li class="col-md-3"><a data-toggle="tab"  href="#menu1">Question Bank</a></li>
<li class="col-md-3"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Summary</a></li>
<li class="col-md-3"><a data-toggle="tab"  href="#menu3">Videos</a></li>
 </ul>
 <hr>
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
 <?php 
include "notes.php"
?>
<br><br><hr>
<div class="col-md-12"> 
</div>
</div>
```

Notes.php contain the code for filter which is in enclose in form

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
 $('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "filter_form.php",
        data: $("#filter_search").serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#home').html('<img src="/img/loading.gif" />');
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#home').html(data);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>  

form action="" method="GET" id="filter_search">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav container-fluid col-md-12">

      <li class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" name="select_category">

       <option value="category">Select Category</option>

                    <?php
                        $sql1 = mysqli_query($conn,"call category_dropdown()");
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1))
                        {   

                            echo "<option value='" . $row['category'] ."'>" . $row['category'] . "</option>";
                        }
                        mysqli_free_result($sql1);
                        mysqli_next_result($conn);
                    ?> 
                </select>



    </li>
   <li class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"     name="select_course"></a>

          <option value="course">Select Course</option>

                    <?php
                        $sql2 = mysqli_query($conn,"call courses_dropdown()");
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2))
                        {   

                            echo "<option value='" . $row['courses'] ."'>" . $row['courses'] . "</option>";
                        }
                        mysqli_free_result($sql2);
                        mysqli_next_result($conn);
                    ?> 
                </select>


    </li>

        <li class="col-sm-3">
        <select class="form-control dropdown-toggle"  name="select_subject">
        <option value="subjects">Select Subjects</option> 
        <?php
         $sql3 = mysqli_query($conn,"call subject_dropdown()");
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3))
         {   
             echo "<option value='" . $row['subjects'] ."'>" . $row['subjects'] . "</option>";
          }
          mysqli_free_result($sql3);
                        mysqli_next_result($conn);
        ?>
        </select> 

    </li>

    <li class="col-md-3">
        <input type="submit"  name="filter" class="btn form-control btn-warning" value="Filter Results">
    </li>   
</ul>
</form>
```

**filter_search.php**

```
     <?php
  include 'includes/dbconfig.php';
  if(isset($_GET['id']))
                        {
                            $id=$_GET['id'];
                            $start=($id-1)*$limit;
                        }
                        else{
                            $id=1;
                        }
     if(isset($_GET['filter']))
                  {
                    $start = 0;
                    $limit = 16;
                    $category = $_GET['select_category'];
                    $course = $_GET['select_course'];
                    $subject = $_GET['select_subject'];
                          $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"call   filter('category','course','subject')") or die('Query failed: '. mysqli_error($conn));

                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                          {   
                            $title = $row['title'];
                            $description = $row['description'];
                            $url = $row['content_url'];
                            $icon = $row['thumb_icon'];

                          ?>

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                 <a href="<?php echo $url ;?>">
                              <div class="well well-sm">
                              <img class="img" alt="PDF" src="<?php echo $icon ;?>" >

                              <h4><small><?php echo $title ; ?></small></h4>

                              <p> <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Preview</a></p>
                              </div>

                          </a>

                      </div>

        <?php
     }
        }
       ?>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Does the ajax call actual have anything in the response? What is it?

Comment: it is showing anonymous function error in script,$ is not defined

Comment: Does the ajax call actual have anything in the response? What is it? You can use the network tab of the developer console to see what exactly you're sending and what exactly is being sent back

Comment: NO response data to show

Comment: But it *should* show something, right? Check the Request headers. Are you sending `id` and `filter` values?

Comment: if it's saying $ is not defined, maybe jQuery is not loaded in your page?

Comment: jquery was missing,i added it but still nothing is showing in tab

Comment: Finally its working ,i changed isset[$_GET['filter'] to if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='get') it is fetching result ,but data is automatically getting hide